# Updating Code, App Stays Same

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem

In my app, I decided to add a UIBarButtonItem for composing an email to the top right of the view.  So, I used this code:

```
UIBarButtonItem *emailing = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCompose target:self action:@selector(emailIt)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = emailing;
```

Absolutely nothing changed in my app, no button was added.  What is going on?

Comment: Is the view controller in a `UINavigationController`?

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40);
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(emailIt) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
UIBarButtonItem *buttonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = buttonItem;
```

But, make sure that you are using UINavigationController

Comment: If the OP's code doesn't work, this won't work either. There's no need to create a custom button to solve the issue.